# Hive with emrfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-emr

I am importing tables from Amazon RDS to Hive using sqoop. The process is working and the data is being stored in the hive default hdfs directory : /user/hive/warehouse.

I need to change the storage location from hdfs to emrfs s3.

It is my understanding that I need to change (in hive-site.xml on the master node) value of the property hive.metastore.warehouse.dir to the s3//bucket/warehouse-location. It appears that I don't have the permission to modify the file hive-site.xml.

I am looking for some advise on how best to do it.

Sudi

Comment: Change to root user.

Answer (score 1):

You will need sudo privileges to modify the hive-site.xml file on the masternode (located in /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml usually).

If this is not an option, try setting this property before the cluster is started. An example with CloudFormation :

```
                "Configurations" : [
                {
                    "Classification" : "hive-site",
                    "ConfigurationProperties" : {
                        "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir" : "s3://your_s3_bucket/hive_warehouse/",
                    }
                }
            ],
```

Or through the EMR dialogue in the section for "Edit Software Settings"

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo vi /etc/hive/conf/hive-site
```

or

```
sudo -su root
vi /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hive in EMR. The hive metastore is recommended to be set in an external DB or use glue data catalog as hive metastore.

For your concern,

Create the tables you want to import as external tables in the hive. While creating the external table you will have to provide the location parameter as s3 location of your table.

Example: Suppose I have s3 bucket named bucket-xyz and I want my data to be stored in s3://bukcet-xyz/my-table location, where my table name is my-table. Then I will create my-table as an external table using hive.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my-table (A VARCHAR(30), B DOUBLE(9))
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED ...
LOCATION s3://bukcet-xyz/my-table
```

After this when you will insert data into this table using hive . Hive will store the data in the s3 location you specified.